# How to select Voice-Over output speaker on IOS App

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover

I'm currently working on a an Iphone app for people suffering of visual impairment. In order to get an input text, the app uses voice recognition.
The app runs pretty well with Voice-Over activated, but when the user launch the voice recognition, Voice-Over output switch to the ear speaker (and that's normal).

What bothers me, is that when all the process is over, the output speaker doesn't switch back to main speaker even if I end all the processes.

For the Voice recognition I created an instance of `AVAudioEngine()`, `SFSpeechRecognizer()`, `SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()` and `SFSpeechRecognitionTask?`.

Then I tapped the request into the live input node and started the audioengine.

After the user finished to speak, I called `audioEngine.stop()`, `request.endAudio()` and `recognitionTask?.cancel()` to stop everything and go back to a "normal" use of the app.

Maybe I missed something when stoping everything, something about the live input node tapped :
`audioEngine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in self.request.append(buffer)}`

But I tried to `removeTap(onBus: 0)` but nothing changed.

The output speaker comes back to normal only when I close the app or going to multitasking.

I hope you could help me figure it out !

Thanks